# Can every commutative ring of characteristic $p\in\mathbb P$ be written as the form $R/(p)$ with $R$ being a ring of characteristic $0$?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ac.commutative-algebra

All rings here are associative, commutative and unital. By a ring of characteristic zero (resp. of characteristic $p$, for prime $p$) I mean a ring $A$ such that the canonical homomorphism $\mathbb Z\to A$ is injective (resp. factors through $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

A simple observation (from the comments) is that whenever $S$ is a ring of characteristic $p$ then there exists a ring of characteristic zero $R$ and an isomorphism $R/(p)\cong S$: for instance we can simply take $R=S\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Is there a "universal" such construction, in the following sense

> Given a ring $S$ of characteristic $p$, does there exist a ring $R$ of characteristic zero $R$ and a fixed isomorphism $R/(p)\cong S$, such that for every ring characteristic zero $R'$ of characteristic zero and homomorphism from a ring of characteristic zero into $S$ can be lifted to a homomorphism $R\to R'$ (i.e., so that the homomorphism $R'\to S$ equals the composite map $R'\to R\twoheadrightarrow R/(p)\cong S$)

?

Note that such $R\twoheadrightarrow S$ does not have to be minimal (as homomorphisms above are not required to be surjective).

I think that the above question is equivalent (or related) to: if for every $\mathbb Z_{p}$-polynomial algebra $A$ and ideal $I$ of $A$ containing $p$, there exists an ideal $J$ not containing nonzero constants such that $I=(p)+J$. But I'm not sure if the latter simplifies the former.

Comment: This is a cross-post of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313245/can-any-commutative-ring-of-characteristic-p-in-mathbb-p-be-written-as-the-for

Comment: There's certainly no reason to expect a universal such lift. Already there's no universal lift when $S = \mathbb{F}_4$; here any algebra of the form $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 - ax - b)$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ are odd is a lift.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I agree with you, but I failed to give a rigorous proof...

Comment: For the existence, take $R=S\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Great idea! Don't you think of posting it as an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by characteristic zero ring?

Comment: Maybe it's best to post the trivial answer to MathSE and close the question here. As pointed out by Vinteuil, a correct definition of "characteristic zero" is still missing: for non-domains it allows at least two natural distinct definitions. Also for the second question $\mathbf{Z}/p\mathbf{Z}$ has no unique minimal lifts: for instance for prime $p\equiv 1[4]$ both $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ are minimal lifts (being f.g. domains of Krull dim 1, all their proper quotients are finite).

Comment: @YCor What are those definitions of characteristic $0$? I am only aware of one (which does not need the ring to be a domain), namely that there is no way to get $0$ by adding $1$ to itself a positive number of times.

Comment: (1) $x\mapsto nx$ *is injective for every nonzero integer* $n$ (2) *no nonzero integer annihilates the ring*. Of course (1) implies (2) (except for the zero module), but $\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ satisfies (2) and not (1).

Comment: @YCor Ahh, I see (and I agree that there is indeed no obvious choice here).

Comment: It seems obvious to me that (1) is the correct definition, at least in the context of this question.  I don't really understand the votes to close here.

Comment: @YCor I've made the definition of "characteristic $0$" more precise, though I never heard of your first definition of "characteristic $0$".

Comment: @YCor As for my second question, I absolutely don't mean minimal lift, but universal lift.

Comment: I have given the final vote to close, until the question is made more precise.

Comment: @Joël So what kind of "precise" do you expect for?

Comment: @Censi Li: Perhaps I have not said exactly what I meant: I meant a formulation of the question that makes it non-trivial. As it stands, it has the trivial answer $R=S \times \mathbb Z$ as proposed by LMB, and it is too easy a question for MO. If you can reformulate it in a way it has a non-trivial and useful answer, then I would be happy to vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Joël I have to say your last comment mentioned nothing related to "precise". And my post consists of two questions, and only received a trivial answer for the first one.

Comment: But then your second question needs precisions. It seemed to me it has been answered by Qiaochu's comment. But if you think otherwise, it is that I haven't understood the question as you intended it. Do you ask for which $S$ there exists a universal $R$? Anyway, I think you should throughly edit your question, removing the first question which has a trivial answer (or leaving it but indicating it has a trivial answer) and emphasizing the second one, formulated more carefully...

Comment: @CensiLI: have you read first the comments? First, with your definition of char. zero (which is (2) of my comment), your first question as a trivial uninteresting answer (the stupid product as in LBM's comment). Second, your second universality question is weird because if you don't assume uniqueness of the lift it's not a universal property.

Comment: @Joël: I indeed first understood it as "minimal lift" but it's not what's asked (regardless whether uniqueness is included or not in the definition)

Comment: @Joël I admitted that my second question need rephrasing. But since so many people think I should delete my first question because it received a trivial and uninteresting answer. I think I'd better post a new question, since that trivial and uninteresting answer in the comment do make sense for me.

Comment: A remark: assume $R\to S$ is universal in the weak sense (no uniqueness). Then every intermediate ring between $R$ and $S$, of char 0, still satisfies the lifting property. So we can assume that $R$ has the property that every nonzero ideal contains a nonzero integer. A compactness argument implies that some prime ideal contains no nonzero integer, so $R$ is a domain. Then $R\otimes\mathbf{Q}$ is a field. If $S$ has prime char. $p$, then we can lift the nontrivial $\mathbf{Z}_p\to S$, making $R$ a $\mathbf{Z}_p$-module, and $R[1/p]$ is a field.

Comment: @YCor Got it, thank you very much...

Comment: @YCor Thank you very much for helping improving my question considerably. However, your remark reminded me that it's unwise of me to stick to $p$ as the kernel (In fact, your proof that $R$ can be chosen to be integral domain inspired me to consider $\mathbf{Z}_p[\sqrt p]\twoheadrightarrow \mathbb Z_p$, which leads to a contradiction).

Comment: @YCor So now the question becomes if there exists a morphism $R\twoheadrightarrow S$ for $R$ zero characteristic and $S$ $p$ characteristic stratifying the universal property. I realized that this new question is sharply different to the oringinal ones, which turn out to be not of much interest... So think I'd better make a new posting...